AWS S3 credentials in java
I'm tasked with writing a file into our S3 bucket from java.
I have set up the IAM role. I have a certificate, a private key, a trust-anchor-arn, a profile-arn, and a role-arn.
I can then make an S3Client using a ProcessCredentialsProvider that calls out to aws_signing_helper, which returns json that includes fields for AccessKeyId, SessionToken, etc.  This works.
I do not want to call out to an external process. There doesn't seem to be a way using pure java to make the API calls.
Is it possible to get the credentials without calling out to an external program?  If so, how?

These concepts are explained in the AWS SDK for Java V2 Developer Guide. See this topic:
Configure SDK authentication
Once you select a credentials provider, you can create a S3AsyncClient to place a file into an S3 bucket.
/**
     * Uploads a local file to an AWS S3 bucket asynchronously.
     *
     * @param bucketName the name of the S3 bucket to upload the file to
     * @param key        the key (object name) to use for the uploaded file
     * @param objectPath the local file path of the file to be uploaded
     * @return a {@link CompletableFuture} that completes with the {@link PutObjectResponse} when the upload is successful, or throws a {@link RuntimeException} if the upload fails
     */
    public CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> uploadLocalFileAsync(String bucketName, String key, String objectPath) {
        PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();

        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> response = getAsyncClient().putObject(objectRequest, AsyncRequestBody.fromFile(Paths.get(objectPath)));
        return response.whenComplete((resp, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to upload file", ex);
            }
        });
    }

credentails file
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <Value>
aws_secret_access_key = <Value>
region = us-east-1

Once you setup that file, your AWS Service clients will pick up your keys.

Thanks.  I understand how to put the file.  I don't understand how to get the credentials, or how to set trust-anchor-arn, profile-arn, or role-arn in any of the other providers.

Using your keys can be done in serveral ways. You can use the shared credentials and config files. Here you place a file named credentials under C:\Users<user name>.aws.  See updated part of my response.

Thanks again.
I have .pem cert files for certificate and key.  I don't know what keys to use for those in the credentials file.  I don't know where to put the arns (trust-anchor, profile, and role).
I think I'm getting closer with an AssumeRoleRequest and StaticCredentialsProvider, but it's still failing, and I think part of it is because it doesn't know the arn's

Do you have your AWS key and secret key? Google how to get AWS keys.

I have a cert, private key, and arn's for trust-anchor, profile, and role.  It all works when I call out to aws_signing_helper using a ProcessCredentialsProvider.  I don't want to call an external program for this, though, so I'm looking for how to do it using a different implementation of AWSCredentialsProvider.
